# Bootstrap search bar with both clear x and a search icon add on

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

Want to make a search bar in Bootstrap 3 with both the clear glypicon that only appears if there is text, AND the search glypicon that the user clicks to start their search.

I am close:

[image]

However, as you can see the x glyph occupies the same space as the search bar. If I try to just position the x farther to the left, it disappears behind the search bar.

My code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/cc_CommonSearchBar.css" />
    </xp:this.resources>
    <div class="input-group" style="width:300px">
        <!--        <div class="btn-group">-->
        <input id="ccSearchInput" type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Search for..." />
        <span id="ccSearchClear" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" />
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ccSearchInput").keyup(function(){   
        $("#ccSearchClear").toggle(Boolean(this.value));
    });
            $("#ccSearchClear").toggle(Boolean($("#ccSearchInput").val()));
            $("#ccSearchClear").click(function(){
        $("#ccSearchInput").val("").focus();
        $("#ccSearchClear").hide();
        }); 
});]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```

And my CSS:

```
#ccSearchInput {
    width: 200px;
}

#ccSearchClear {    
    position:absolute !important;
    right:5px !important;
    top:0 !important;
    bottom:0 !important;
    height:14px !important; 
    margin:auto !important;
    font-size:14px !important;
    cursor:pointer !important;
    color:#ccc !important;;
}
```

Comment: can you put the generated HTML and necessary CSS into a fiddle for easier troubleshooting? (http://jsfiddle.net) - keep in mind to only add what's necessary (read creating a [mcve])

Comment: Sure. This is my first fiddle, so let me know if is not correct.  https://jsfiddle.net/bryanschmiedeler/jso8663q/

Comment: I added a possible answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I structured your HTML and JavaScript differently (positive note: reduces your CSS)

Let me know if this works ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($("#ccSearchInput").val() === '') {
    $("#clearBtn").hide();
  }

  $("#ccSearchInput").on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      $("#clearBtn").show();
    } else {
      $("#clearBtn").hide();
    }
  });

  $("#clearBtn").click(function() {
    $("#ccSearchInput").val('').focus();
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#basic-addon2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<hr/>
<div class="row" style="float:right">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ccSearchInput" placeholder="Search for...">
      <div class="input-group-addon" id="clearBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-addon" id="searchBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <span class="" id="ccSearchClear"></span> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You bet that works! Thanks a ton. That is some very nice code.